# How to multiply decimals using expr

Tags: shell, expr

When I run the following command:

```
expr 1.2 * 13
```

I get this error:

```
expr: syntax error: unexpected argument '12'
```

I expect I am missing a syntax. What is it?

Comment: You have to escape the asterisk

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk is expanded as a glob, so you'll end-up running something like `expr 1.2 file1 file2 13`

Also, <s>the shell **cannot** do arithmetic with floating point numbers</s> floating point arithmetic with the shell isn’t standard:

```bash
expr 1.2 \* 13
expr: non-integer argument
```

You'll need to use a command like `bc`/`awk`/etc... or convert your numbers to integers:

```bash
echo '1.2 * 13' | bc
15.6

awk 'BEGIN{ print 1.2 * 13 }'
15.6

expr 12 \* 13 / 10
15
```

Comment: @ Fravadona : `"the shell cannot do arithmetic with floating point numbers"` ??? ::::::::::: `echo $(( 4.9 * 5.111 ))` ——> `25.043900000000001` :::::::::::: `expr $(( 2.7182818 ** 3.1415928 ))`  ——> `23.140695259694844`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto, ..."right", if you're okay with getting into the habit of writing code that's buggy on any standard-compliant shell. For someone who's a professional system administrator, that's dangerous. (Apple "chooses" to use an ancient version of bash because they're unwilling to be subject to GPLv3 license terms required for any build upstream shipped in over a decade, so the version of that they ship is exceptionally awful, with an ever-growing list of features it doesn't support; that's putting business concerns over customer wellbeing if I've ever seen it)